# Was there any creative interaction between the makers of The Dark Crystal and The Last Unicorn?

Tags: dark-crystal, the-last-unicorn

I just watched *The Last Unicorn* with my son.  It was the first time I had seen it in a long time, and both he and I were struck by the similarity in the beak design between Celaeno the harpy and the Chamberlain from *The Dark Crystal*.

[image: Calaeno the harpy]

[image: skekSil the Chamberlain (with the skekUng the Garthim Master, later the emperor)]

Obviously, both monsters' beaks were ultimately inspired by those of carrion vultures.

[image: Turkey Vulture]

And I had previously dismissed the similarity as just a coincidence.  However, what occurred to me with today's viewing was that, in fact, both films were being worked on at the same time, and they were both bankrolled by [Lew Grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lew_Grade)'s ITC media company.  So it occurred to me that there might actually have been some creative cross-pollination between the two projects.

Is there any evidence of this—that there were any creative interaction between the Henson people working on *The Dark Crystal* and the Rankin-Bass people making *The Last Unicorn*.

Answer (score 2):

IMDB indicates that there was only *one* [crossover crew member](https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt0083791,tt0084237) (e.g. someone who worked on both films), that being [**John Richards**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0724162/) who worked as a Music Recordist on Dark Crystal and Recording Engineer on Last Unicorn. As you've mentioned, Lew Grade is listed as the producer on both, but it's highly unlikely that he would have had any day-to-day involvement in the production and its artwork choices.

You might want to note that vultures have been depicted in a similar way in earlier animated features such as [Robin Hood (1973)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood_(1973_film)), so this is likely just a nod to how they actually look.

[image]